# I can send data to the Arduino but I can't receive data from it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, arduino, serial-port

I've made a windows form application, in this form I want to read and write serial data to my Pro Micro.
Sending the data to the µC works as it should, but I can't read from it.
Even more, the µC doesn't send the data.

Right now I removed all unnecessary code and the µC should just echo what I sent.
When I use this in the Arduino serial monitor it all works, I write the data and it returns it.
But when try this in the windows form it doesn't.
Then I decided to measure the tx pin of the µC and it didn't send any data at all, although the received data was the right.
There was a difference in pulse length but I think that is not enough to cause this, the form had a duration of 0.1039ms (making a frequency of 9.624 Hz) and the Arduino monitor had a duration of 0.1041ms (making a frequency of 9.606 Hz).

Here is my code:

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UART
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.TopMost = true;    // Window always on top
            this.AutoSize = true;   // The size of the window will always be as small as possible while still showing all content
            serial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(mySerialPort_DataReceived);
            lblInvalidPort.Hide();
            tbWriteInput.Enabled = false;
            btnSend.Enabled = false;

            // Show all ports in the ports combobox and sellect the curently used option
            combPort.Items.Clear();
            combPort.Items.AddRange(SerialPort.GetPortNames());
            combPort.SelectedItem = serial.PortName;
        }

        private void serial_ErrorReceived(object sender, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            rtbRead.Text = e.ToString() + "\n" + rtbRead.Text;
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

        private void combPort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Show all ports in the ports combobox and sellect the curently used option
            combPort.Items.Clear();
            combPort.Items.AddRange(SerialPort.GetPortNames());
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnConnect.Text.ToLower().Equals("connect"))
            {
                try
                {
                    serial.PortName = combPort.Text;
                    serial.BaudRate = 9600;
                    serial.Open();
                    lblInvalidPort.Hide();
                    tbWriteInput.Enabled = true;
                    btnSend.Enabled = true;
                    btnConnect.Text = "Disconnect";
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    lblInvalidPort.Show();
                    MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    tbWriteInput.Enabled = false;
                    btnSend.Enabled = false;
                }
            }

            else if (btnConnect.Text.ToLower().Equals("disconnect"))
            {
                serial.Close();
                tbWriteInput.Enabled = false;
                btnSend.Enabled = false;
                btnConnect.Text = "Connect";
            }
        }

        private void serial_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Got some data", "Serial", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            rtbRead.Text = serial.ReadExisting() + "\n" + rtbRead.Text;
        }

        private static void mySerialPort_DataReceived(
                   object sender,
                   SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            MessageBox.Show("Got some data", "Serial", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

        private void tbWriteInput_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
            {
                rtbWrite.Text = tbWriteInput.Text + "\n" + rtbWrite.Text;
                serial.Write(tbWriteInput.Text);
            }
        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rtbWrite.Text = tbWriteInput.Text + "\n" + rtbWrite.Text;
            serial.Write(tbWriteInput.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Arduino:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    while(Serial.available() == 0);
    while(Serial.available() > 0) Serial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting an InvalidOperationException due to cross-threading in the serial_DataReceived event.

Comment: I fixed that by now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I found the problem while working on a 3rd version, you need to add `serial.DtrEnable = true;` in order for it to word.